# Can a minister be removed from the Council of the EU?

Tags: european-union, european-parliament, european-council

In law, is there any provision that enables a minister to be removed from their position in the Council of the EU? Is there a removal process?

What about the European Council? Is there any way to remove a head of state from the European Council?

What about an MEP in the European Parliament, can you remove them?

I'm asking in terms of legality, is there anything in the treaties or national laws that allow for a removal procedure?

Comment: I think this is three separate questions - one about the Council of the EU, one about the European Council, and one about the European Parliament. You might need to split this up and ask each one separately.

Comment: You need to be more specific on "removed by whom"? If you're talking about Council of Ministers removing their own member, then no. But the ministers could be removed from the Council by virtue of being removed as minsiter in their home country.

Answer (score 1):

The [Council of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_the_European_Union) is made up of representatives of the member countries' respective governments, who are appointed by that government. Denying a member state a seat on that council would be tantamount to throwing them out of the EU, which is not possible.

European Council members who are not heads of government/state have specific options, like the [vote of censure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_of_no_confidence#European_Union) against a Commission.

For MEPs, there are national rules depending on where the MEP came from.

Comment: A key point to be made is that the council of the European Union is not a fixed body. The individual attending the session from each national government varies depending on the committee within the council that is meeting, reflecting the holder of responsibility for the equivalent position in the national government.

Comment: @Jontia, AFAIK any country can send an ambassador instead of the specific cabinet official, so it is even more in the hands of that government.